# How to pass nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree to local nixpkgs repository

Tags: nix, nixos

I want to use hubstaff package from [local nixpkgs repository](https://github.com/srghma/dotfiles/blob/fd6a8e8f49e51da7e583ef00beef067b1c527ecb/nixos/root/nixpkgs/default.nix#L8),

```
let
  # pass config so that packages use correct allowUnfree for example
  nixpkgs-local = import /home/bjorn/projects/nixpkgs { inherit config; };
in

rec {
  config.allowUnfree = true;

  config.packageOverrides = old: {

    # packages from local nixpkgs
    inherit (nixpkgs-local) safeeyes hubstaff;
....
```

but its unfree package, so throws unfree package error

```
$ sudo nixos-rebuild dry-build
building the system configuration...
error: Package ‘hubstaff-1.3.1-ff75f26’ in /home/bjorn/projects/nixpkgs/pkgs/applications/misc/hubstaff/default.nix:60 has an unfree license (‘unfree’), refusing to evaluate.
```

As I understand I need to pass `nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true`, but `import /home/bjorn/projects/nixpkgs { inherit config; };` above is not working

---

P.S.

other issue I have is that I have tried to peek what value I am passing in `config.nixpkgs.allowUnfree` [here](https://github.com/srghma/dotfiles/blob/fd6a8e8f49e51da7e583ef00beef067b1c527ecb/nixos/root/default.nix#L69)

```
{ config, pkgs, lib, ... }:

let r = {
  imports = [
    ./hardware-configuration.nix
    ./hardware-configuration-override.nix
    ./hardware-programs.nix
    /home/bjorn/projects/nixpkgs/nixos/modules/services/misc/safeeyes.nix
  ];

  ....
};

in
builtins.seq (lib.debug.showVal config.nixpkgs.allowUnfree) r
```

but I get [infinite recursion error](https://pastebin.com/NzFzsPFY), maybe someone knows the way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tnx to tilpner

I was passing wrong config

Namely,
this is config that `import /home/bjorn/projects/nixpkgs` was expecting

```
nix-repl> c = import <nixpkgs/nixos> {}

nix-repl> c.config.nixpkgs
{ config = { ... }; overlays = [ ... ]; pkgs = { ... }; system = "x86_64-linux"; }
```

This is what I was passing

```
nix-repl> c.config
{ _module = { ... }; assertions = [ ... ]; boot = { ... }; config = { ... }; containers = { ... }; dysnomia = { ... }; ec2 = { ... }; environment = { ... }; fileSystems = { ... }; fonts = { ... }; gnu = false; hardware = { ... }; i18n = { ... }; ids = { ... }; jobs = «error: The option `jobs' is used but not defined.»; kde = { ... }; krb5 = { ... }; lib = { ... }; meta = { ... }; nesting = { ... }; networking = { ... }; nix = { ... }; nixpkgs = { ... }; passthru = «error: The option `passthru' is used but not defined.»; power = { ... }; powerManagement = { ... }; programs = { ... }; security = { ... }; services = { ... }; sound = { ... }; swapDevices = [ ... ]; system = {
```

Its the one that passed to /etc/nixos/configuration.nix

Fix:

```
{ config, pkgs }:

let
  # pass config so that packages use correct allowUnfree for example
  unfreeConfig = config.nixpkgs.config // {
    allowUnfree = true;
  };
  nixpkgs-local = import /home/bjorn/projects/nixpkgs { config = unfreeConfig; };
in
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second "P.S." question, here's the reason why and suggestions what to do instead.

The infinite recursion occurs because the module system needs to evaluate the 'root' of every module and some attributes like `imports` in order to build the term that represents the root of `config`.

With your call to `seq` you're evaluating an attribute of `config` at a point where `config` itself is still being evaluated.

Technically, you can solve this by adding your `seq` call to an attribute instead of around the entire module. This way, `config` can be evaluated without evaluating your `seq` call.

Probably an easier way to have a look at your configuration is to import it in `nix repl`

```
nix-repl> c = import <nixpkgs/nixos> { configuration = ./nixos/root/default.nix; /* or the file usually called configuration.nix */ }

nix-repl> c.config.nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree
true
```

You can use the `:r` command to reload all files when iterating. Nix likes to cache them because the implementation is geared toward batch execution.